# Referencing for element in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Answer is not $array[0];

My array is setup as follows

```
$array = array();
$array[7] =  37;
$array[19] = 98;
$array[42] = 22;
$array[68] = 14;
```

I'm sorting the array and trying to get the highest possible match out after the sorting. So in this case $array[19] = 98; 
I only need the value 98 back and it will *always* be in the first position of the array. I can't reference using $array[0] as the 0 key doesn't exist. Speed constraints mean I can't loop through the array to find the highest match.

There also has to be a better solution than

```
foreach ( $array as $value )
{
    echo $value;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
echo $array[$keys[0]];
```

Or you could use the [current()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function:

```
reset($array);
$value = current($array);
```

Comment: You may want to call reset() on the array before current() to make sure you're at the first element, though.

Comment: Thanks. Current works perfectly. There are other constraints which stop me copying the array or even the indexes. Speed is also a big one in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You want the first key in the array, if I understood your question correctly:

```
$firstValue = reset($array);
$firstKey = key($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always do ;

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

And now $array[0] will be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first element you can use [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), this will not loop anything and return only the value.

In your example however, it is not the first element so there seems to be a discrepancy in your example/question, or an error in my understanding thereof.

Comment: array_shift() is better than current(), since it doesn't depend on the internal array pointer. If you use next($arr) and then current($arr) it will return a different value. Even though this won't be the case, it's less elegant than array_shift() that _always_ returns the first element.

Comment: Array_shift will shorten the array. In this case I just need the value to work on before processing the array further in another section of the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting it, you can specify your own sorting routine and have it pick out the highest value *while* you are sorting it.

Comment: The actual sorting is happening through another part of the system. Effectively a blackbox which I can't control.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_values($array);
echo $array[0];
```